# Does the uniform convergence imply continuity?

Tags: real-analysis

In a proof I am reading, the author claims that

for $f(t)=\begin{cases}1\text{ if }t\in[\frac{2}{3},1]\\0\text{ if } t\in [0,\frac{1}{3}]\\3t-1\text{ if } (\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3})\end{cases}$

$x(t)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}2^{-k-1}f(3^{2k}t)$ and $y(t)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}2^{-k-1}f(3^{2k+1}t)$ is continuous by the Weierstrass M-Test, but I don't see why. Can anyone elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if $f_n\to f$ uniformly , $f_n$ is continuous $\forall n$, then $f$ is continuous. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337740/does-uniform-convergence-of-a-sequence-of-functions-imply-uniform-continuity-of) is the idea of proof.

In your example, $f$ is continuous and bounded, $x_n(t)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}2^{-k-1}f(3^{2k}t)$ is also continuous, and $x_n\to x$ uniformly by M-test, so $x$ is continuous.

Comment: If $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly and $f$ is continuous is $f_n$ continuous for all n?

Comment: @LukeTaylor No. Think about $f_n$ being a modification of $f=0$ at only one point $x_0$, and the value $f_n(x_0)$ converges to $f(x_0)$.